# Cannot change apache document root

Tags: apache, document-root

Someone configured centos server for me. In httpd.conf I found:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/hmtl"
```

Under html folder there is another folder named "analysis". I put test1.html in /html folder and test2.html in /analysis folder. Now if I browse to

```
http://my-server-domain.com/test1.html
```

it returns not found, but

```
http://my-server-domain.com/test2.html
```

shown without error. How come DocumentRoot is not "/var/www/hmtl" but "/var/www/hmtl/analysis"? I thought there may be symlink or something but, /html folder seems to be empty, except my text1.html file.